# Quarkus kubernetesMockServer for application initialization

Tags: unit-testing, kubernetes, junit, quarkus, fabric8

I am working on a Quarkus application to acct as an Operator in a OpenShift/Kubernetes cluster. When writing the tests using a kubernetesMockServer it is working fine for REST calls to developed application but when code runs inside an Initialization Block it is failing, in the log I see that mock server is replying with a 404 error:

```
2020-02-17 11:04:12,148 INFO  [okh.moc.MockWebServer] (MockWebServer /127.0.0.1:53048) MockWebServer[57577] received request: GET /apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 404 Client Error
```

On the TestCode I have:

```java
@QuarkusTestResource(KubernetesMockServerTestResource.class)
@QuarkusTest
class TestAIRController {

    @MockServer
    KubernetesMockServer mockServer;

    private CustomResourceDefinition crd;
    private CustomResourceDefinitionList crdlist;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        crd = new CustomResourceDefinitionBuilder()
            .withApiVersion("apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1")
            .withNewMetadata().withName("types.openshift.example-cloud.com")
            .endMetadata()
            .withNewSpec()
            .withNewNames()
            .withKind("Type")
            .withPlural("types")
            .endNames()
            .withGroup("openshift.example-cloud.com")
            .withVersion("v1")
            .withScope("Namespaced")
            .endSpec()
            .build();
        crdlist = new CustomResourceDefinitionListBuilder().withItems(crd).build();
        mockServer.expect().get().withPath("/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions")
            .andReturn(200, crdlist)
            .always();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        RestAssured.when().get("/dummy").then().body("size()", Is.is(0));
    }

}
```

The dummy rest is using the same code for searching the CRD, and in fact when running withouth the class observing the startup event it works fine

```java
@Path("/dummy")
public class Dummy {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dummy.class); 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response listCRDs(){
        KubernetesClient oc = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        CustomResourceDefinition crd = oc.customResourceDefinitions()
                .list().getItems().stream()
                    .filter( ob -> ob.getMetadata().getName().equals("types.openshift.example-cloud.com"))
                    .findFirst().get();
        LOGGER.info("CRD NAME is {}", crd.getMetadata().getName());
        return Response.ok(new ArrayList<String>()).build();
    }
}
```

Finally this is an except of the

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AIRWatcher {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AIRWatcher.class);

    void OnStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        KubernetesClient oc = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        CustomResourceDefinition crd = oc.customResourceDefinitions()
                .list().getItems().stream()
                    .filter( ob -> ob.getMetadata().getName().equals("types.openshift.example-cloud.com"))
                    .findFirst().get();
        LOGGER.info("Using {}", crd.getMetadata().getName());

    }

}
```

It's like for some reason the mock server is still not initialized for the Startup event, is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the Mock Server is only configured to respond right before the test execution, while this code:

```
void OnStart(@Observes StartupEvent ev) {
        KubernetesClient oc = new DefaultKubernetesClient();
        CustomResourceDefinition crd = oc.customResourceDefinitions()
                .list().getItems().stream()
                    .filter( ob -> ob.getMetadata().getName().equals("types.openshift.example-cloud.com"))
                    .findFirst().get();
        LOGGER.info("Using {}", crd.getMetadata().getName());

    }
```

runs when the application is actually comes up (which is before any `@BeforeEach` runs).

Can you please open an issue on the Quarkus Github? This should be something we provide a solution for

Comment: Ticket opened in Git -> https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/7232